# Django query set latest object having a particular foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a profile model

```
class Profile(models.model):
    user=models.Foreignkey(user,null=True,blank=True)
```

and

```
class Moods(models.model):
    email=models.CharField(null=True,blank=True)
    mood=models.CharField(null=True,blank=True)
```

for  a single email there may be many mood like..

```
test@test.com happy
test@test.com sad
```

I want to get a queryset such that the email belongs to a user who has a foreign key in Profile model and the mood is the latest mood that is created for that user

Answer (score 0):

If your db backend is postgresql, you can use [`distinct(*fields)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct):

```
Moods.objects\
    .filter(email__in=User.objects.filter(profile_set__isnull=False).values_list('email', flat=True))\
    .order_by('email', '-pk')\  # group by email, latest first
    .distinct('email')  # pick first for each email
```

The restrictions mentioned by @e4c5 with regard to the primary key not being a definitive indicator of record creation order still apply. Also note that `email` is not unique in `auth.User`, thus if users share the same email, only the latest mood of any of them will be in the queryset.